# WebFlux/Reactor: checking conditions before+after Flux execution with doOnComplete

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm already querying some external resource with `Flux.using()`. Now I want to implement a kind of optimistic locking: read some state before query starts to execute and check if it was updated after query is finished. If so - throw some exception to break http request handling.

I've achieved this by using `doOnComplete`:

```
final AtomicReference<String> initialState = new AtomicReference<>();

return Flux.just("some", "constant", "data")
    .doOnComplete(() -> initialState.set(getState()))
    .concatWith(Flux.using(...)) //actual data query
    .doOnComplete(() -> {if (!initialState.get().equals(getState())) throw new RuntimeException();})
    .concatWithValues("another", "constant", "data")
```

My questions:

1. Is it correct? Is it guaranteed that 1st `doOnComplete` lambda would be finished before `Flux.using()` and is it guaranteed that 2nd `doOnComplete` lambda would be executed strictly after?
2. Does more elegant solution exists?

Answer (score 2):

The first `doOnComplete` would be executed after `Flux.just("some", "constant", "data")` emits all elements and the second one after emitted Publisher defined in `concatWith` completes successfully. This is working because both publishers have a finite number of elements.

With the proposed approach, however the pre-/postconditions from a particular operation are handled outside of the operations at a higher level. In other words, the condition check belonging to the operation is leaking to the flux definition.

Suggestion, pushing the condition check down to the operation:

```java
var otherElements = Flux.using( // actual data query
        () -> "other",
        x -> {
            var initialState = getState();
            return Flux.just(x).doOnComplete(() ->
                { if (!initialState.equals(getState())) throw new IllegalStateException(); }
            );
        },
        x -> { }
);

Flux.just("some", "constant", "data")
        .concatWith(otherElements)
        .concatWith(Mono.just("another")) // "constant", "data" ...
```